# Single word for "less mass per unit volume" (the complement of "dense")

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, antonyms, science

I've been looking for the antonym of *dense*. I'm looking for an exact opposite: a single word the means, precisely, "having *less mass per unit volume* than another object".

That is, I'm seeking a scientific word which could be put into this sentence, and have it make sense:

> Wood is more `_____` than metal

To mean precisely the opposite of:

> Metal is *denser* than wood

And precisely the same as:

> Wood is *less dense* than metal

Only using a single word (as an atomic comparative), as opposed to the two words "*less dense*".

As analogies, we have the pairs "*heavy*"/"*light*" and "*thin*"/"*thick*", and thus needn't to resort to circumlocutions like "*more massive*" or "*less wide*".

For similar reasons, I find "*light*" (the opposite of "*heavy*") and "*spread out*" (the opposite of "*congested*", i.e. "smaller *population* per unit volume") unsatisfying. I would like a single, atomic word that enjoys some currency in scientific prose, which means precisely "*less mass per unit volume*".

Comment: _Wood is less dense than metal -- Less Dense_ **IS** a science word.

Comment: How do you define a "science word"?

Comment: @Matt Gutting A quote.

Answer (score 7):

In statistical physics, density is an important concept, and I have not encountered it used in any way to suggest it has an antonym, sorry to say.

So, I would have to conclude that there is no "science word" for *less dense* in a general sense. *Rarified* only applies to gases, and often only to air pressure when discussing the propagation of sound waves.

The intensive property is *density* and when a given material has a larger or smaller value for density than some other material, we just use "more" or "less" as appropriate descriptors.

Depending on your context, you could possibly use the word *diffuse*, which has the general meaning of things that are more spread apart, but I would not consider it an exact antonym to the scientific usage of *dense*.

Comment: Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/364 for the use–mention distinction, please use an italic face not a bold one. It makes the page look too heavy otherwise, and  furthermore runs counter to typographic convention both on this site and in scholarly works. Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/364 for the use–mention distinction, please use an italic face not a bold one. It makes the page look too heavy otherwise, and also runs counter to typographic convention both on this site and in scholarly works. Please do’t use capitalized words for the use–mention distinction, either.

Answer (score 3):

Try sparser or scanter........

Comment: _Sparse_ is a mathematical term used in opposition to _dense_. Good one.

Comment: But _dense_ in mathematics doesn't mean the same thing as _dense_ in physics. Physical density is a measurable and variable property of matter -- a mass noun; mathematical density is a property of ordered sets which is either true or false, with no variation. Physically, _dense_ and _compact_ mean the same thing. Mathematically they don't. And _sparse_ doesn't apply to ordered sets; it's only defined for matrices and other constructs.

Comment: Plus “Wood is sparser than metal” has nothing to do with the density at all, but with how easy the materials in question are to obtain.

Answer (score 3):

Density is a property of all matter.  It is the *mass per unit volume.*  See[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density)

If you are comparing two materials, one will be **more dense** or **less dense** than the other.

This is more appropriate than trying for an antonym-pair (like *heavy/light*)

Comment: Problem is that dense means high density. Denser means more dense.

Answer (score 1):

Rare/rarer.

This is the precise scientific term used to describe something as being not dense/less dense.

Comment: Do you have a citation for that? Can it be used of a homogenous material, as opposed to the distribution of a material in a different matrix? In other words, would anyone on the planet say "wood is *rarer* than iron" to mean wood has less mass per unit volume than iron?

Comment: Yes, relation to density it can be used to describe both things like different gases and different solids. Definition wise it's usually just defined as "Not dense"; see [link](http://www.scrabblefinder.com/word/rare/). Here's an example of it being used to describe a solid - [link](http://www.ekshiksha.org.in/eContent-Show.do?documentId=72)

Comment: Collins specifically indicates that the term is applied only to gases: **rare**: (General Physics) (of a gas, esp the atmosphere at high altitudes) having a low density; thin; rarefied. AHD and RHK Webster's use 'thin' as a synonym here, which is never applied to solids wrt density. Have you a recognised authority (rather than a use in a set of scientific teaching notes) licensing the use of say 'lead is rarer than gold at the same temperature'?

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of *dense* is *[rare](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rare)*, i.e. *wood is rarer than metal, metal is denser than wood*.

> marked by wide separation of component particles :  thin  <sup>(MW)</sup>

I believe you could also use *subtile*, usually used as *not dense, rarefied or thin*.

Comment: An interesting suggestion, but *rare* has an obvious common usage that is entirely different than the desired meaning and would cause readers to constantly have to remind themselves of the intended, extremely secondary meaning, assuming that it had been explicitly spelled out before (especially since wood is clearly more common than metal in the normal sense of the word)... so I don't think it's a good fit.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I've added a dictionary definition to salvage your answer, as this meaning of *rare* is nowadays specialized, and in general usage, it is, well, somewhat rare. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I have given up trying to find a proper scientific term for this property. You can try adding a prefix or suffix to impart the property you want in a way that is clearly understood by audience.

Essentially you want "not dense". Given that "dense" is latin in origin, ***nondense*** seems appropriate, but ***denseless*** seems to have a better ring to it.

> wood is more *denseless* than metal

The reciprocal of density is sometimes referred to its ***specific volume***, so you could say:

> wood has more *specific volume* than metal

But I didn't find a single term related to *specific volume* the same way *dense* relates to *density*.

Comment: @ab2: *specific volume* is related to *specific gravity*, but I was making a pun between *dense* and *sense*.

Answer (score 0):

***specific gravity***

It's not a single word -- I very much doubt you will find a single word -- but it is more scientific-sounding than density.

In your example:

> Wood has a lower specific gravity than metal.

From [Engineering Toolbox](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/density-specific-weight-gravity-d_290.html), Specific Gravity (Relative Density)

> Specific Gravity - SG - is a dimensionless unit defined as the ratio
>   of the density of a substance to the density of water - at a specified
>   temperature

Answer (score 0):

In everyday usage, one might say " Wood is *lighter* than metal " and be understood in most contexts.

Comment: Aluminum as a specific gravity of 2.55 to 2.8 [Engineering Toolbox](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/specific-gravity-solids-metals-d_293.html).  Teak has a specific gravity of 0.55 to 0.66 [wood Database](http://www.wood-database.com/teak/).  [Engineering Toolbox](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wood-density-d_40.html) gives 0.98 as SG of African teak (you have to convert from kg/ cubic meter)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the list of efforts:

(The components of) wood has(/have) a higher ***molar volume*** than metal.

Density in chemistry/physics is a quantity (usually mass) per unit volume: N/V;
Molar volume is its inverse (usually applied to gases): V/N.